# How to make a javascript count up, such as world population?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't know how to make a Javascript count up that is related to the real time, which means when you reload the page, the counter won't start over again. Would anybody tell me how to make that happen :) Example like http://www.worldometers.info/  Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll need to store the data, the first thing that comes to mind is storing it in a database.

Comment: Look at their code, it's there right before your eyes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code they are using is likely pulling from a database with an actual value increasing live.

Check out this [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/not_inept/w5bx1d7q/) I made for an example of how a simple timer can work. Notice that if you press "Run" multiple times, the time itself will stay constant.

Using a remote database will cause a lot more work, but for saving values across browser refreshes you should learn about localStorage I'd check out [W3 School's article](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) on the subject.

In my implementation I use

```
localStorage.setItem("time", currentTime);   // Note that CurrentTime must be a string!
```

in each iteration of your code after setting the `currentTime` var.

When you start up your application, a simple `if` statement

```
if (localStorage.getItem("time") {
    CurrentTime = localStorage.getItem("time");
} else {
    // set default values
}
```

will work, as `localStorage.getItem` will return `null` if the value doesn't exist (or if you set the value to `null` manually).

(for localStorage, you can also use `[bracket notation]` and will probably see that in most common examples)

```
localStorage["foo"] = "value"; 
// is the same as: 
localStorage.setItem("foo", "value")
// and
var bar = localStorage["foo"]; 
// is the same as: 
var bar = localStorage.getItem("foo");
```